# MVVM "binder" definition and its usage?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns, model-view-controller, mvvm

I've been looking around on internet to get a better understanding of `MVVM` in general.

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) it states the components of the `MVVM` pattern are:

- Model
- View
- View Model
- **Binder**

This is the first time I encountered the `binder` definition along with the `model`, `view`, `view-model` that are part of the acronym.

The **Wikipedia definition** of the `MVVM`
's "Binder" states the following:

> Declarative data- and command-binding are implicit in the **MVVM** pattern. In the `Microsoft` solution stack, the `binder` is a `markup language` called **XAML**.
>   The binder frees the developer from being obliged to write boiler-plate logic to synchronize the `view model` and `view`.
>   When implemented outside of the `Microsoft` stack the presence of a declarative `databinding` technology is a key enabler of the pattern.

**Question**: Does every `MVVM` pattern *always* include a `binder`? What is the `binder` *exactly* used for?
Is it something that you actually *code* or is there just some automation going on with the `framework`?

I work and use `AngularJS` almost every day, and some agree that its pattern is `MVVM` as opposed to `MVC`/`MVP`. I got that the `View Model` it's what `AngularJS` calls `"Controller"`, as a reminiscence of "classical" `MVC`.
But does `AngularJS` use a `binder` too? I still haven't seen anything like that while coding in `AngularJS`, maybe the `binder` is just used on a desktop programming framework rather than on browsers?

On Wikipedia it gives `WPF`'s `XAMl` as a `C#` example of `binder`, so what would be the counter-example on `AngularJS`? The `AngularJS`'s `templates` and/or their `syntax` are the `view` and/or `binder` too?

Could you provide a better explanation of the Wikipedia's article, maybe with a couple of examples (`AngularJS` and/or `WPF`)?

**EDIT**: I've looked more on `SO` and found a like to [these slides](http://www.slideshare.net/simbo1905/design-patterns-in-zk-java-mvvm-as-modelviewbinder) which introduce the term `MVB` rather than `MVVM`, so: is this `binder` we're talking about an optional, and does it appear in both `MVVM` and `MVB`?

Does the `binder` just refer to the `data-binding` going on between the `View` and the `View-Model`? How would you represent the `binder` on a chart? Is it just like the "Data-Binding" on [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/mvvm-explained/mvvm.png)?

Thank you.

Comment: The wiki article is written poorly, if they're conflating binders/bindings and xaml.

Comment: I agree. That's why I'm confused and asked here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A "binding" is *something* that describes how data within the View Model will be displayed in the View.  A "binder" is some component that performs the actions described by the binding.  Binders are important to the MVVM framework as they allow you to decouple the View from the ViewModel, and takes the *heavy* weight of handing the synchronization of state between the two.

The binder does the following

- Interprets bindings defined in (typically) the UI
- Observes the View Model for changes in state and updates the View
- Observes the View for changes in state and updates the View Model

Note that the introduction of an initial state is also a change in state, and the act of updating depends on the interpretation of the bindings.

As far as I know, there is no programming language where the concept of *binding* is baked into the language (i.e., synchronizing the state of two instances of an object via language features, like how the Observer pattern is baked into C# as [events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817669.aspx)), so binders must be coded when designing a system that implements the MVVM pattern.

Wikipedia's definition of a binder, as described in your question, is terrible.  They're conflating *markup language* with the act of binding. Xaml, WPF's markup language, is just XML that describes an object graph.  It extends xml through the addition of **[markup extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855815(v=vs.110).aspx)**, which are defined via specifically formatted attribute values.

```
<!-- Attributes that are curly bracketed {} are markup extensions -->
<TextBox x:Name="My textbox lol" Text="{Binding Name}" />
```

The xaml deserializer recognizes these special attributes as markup extensions, which are in fact classes that extend `MarkupExtension`.  The xaml deserializer includes them in the deserialization process.  The Binding class from the above example is a type of `MarkupExtension`, and is the primary (but not the only!) implementation of a binder in WPF.

The binding system in WPF is *very complex*.  It is primarily based on DependencyProperties, but can interact very well with [`INotifyPropertyChanged` properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039505/inotifypropertychanged-wpf) and in a limited way with [POCO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250001/poco-definition) properties.  During deserialization these Bindings are instantiated and configured as described in markup, and then work with the binding subsystem to tie the View and View Model together.

I'm more familiar with knockout than with Angular, but the process is similar.  You define bindings in the UI, which is interpreted by the framework at some point not long after the DOM is constructed. This is triggered by some mechanism determined by the framework itself.  The framework then interprets these bindings in order to bind observable properties within your View Model with the UI.

Without this interpretation work, your binding definitions would just sit there in your HTML, doing nothing.  Something has to interpret them and set up bindings that will handle synchronization of state.

In Knockout, this happens when you call [`ko.applyBindings()`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html), passing in your View Model.  Without calling that, all the `data-bind` binding definitions will sit unused in your html.

How this process happens in each framework, how it is implemented, and what each calls their bindings, can be different.

Comment: Nice answer. Someone should really edit the Wikipedia article though.

Comment: So the binder is something that is always present in a MVVM pattern, but it's usually something related to the framework you're using. You tipically don't have to code that yourself if you use a framework, am I right?

Comment: @Zorgatone Every MVVM framework is going to have code that performs the actions of binders. What they call them and how they implement them is up to the framework.  And pretty much the only reason to use an MVVM framework is for the ability to bind your views to your view models.  I'd wager 80% of every MVVM framework is in the binding system.  It lets you simply describe the binding without having to handle the subscription/unsubscription of listeners yourself.

Comment: Great, as I thought. Thanks buddy

Answer (score 2):

The Wikipedia is not where everything comes from. First, read this blogpost from John Gossman, the architect of WPF and Silverlight:
[Introduction to Model/View/ViewModel pattern for building WPF apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johngossman/archive/2005/10/08/478683.aspx)
See? There is no any "Binder" in there. What he wrote instead is:

> Model/View/ViewModel also relies on one more thing: a general mechanism for data binding.

To understand what MVVM really is read first sentence of this post:

> Model/View/ViewModel is a variation of Model/View/Controller (MVC) that is tailored for modern UI development platforms where the View is the responsibility of a designer rather than a classic developer.

Binding mechanism is not a part of the pattern itself. It's an underlying technology, which is essential for applying the pattern.

Comment: Yes. I see now. I asked because I find Wikipedia was really confusing me

Comment: I wasn't able to find any information about the binder itself. So I thought something on Wikipedia was wrong. Thanks for the clarification